# jQuery first-child nth-child

Tags: jquery

I have the current code below to highlight the top line and date along with the cell of the html table that my mouse is over.  I am still very new to jQuery and dont have a very good grasp on first child/nth child yet with it.  Instead of highlighting the item # I want to highlight the Product Name (second th down in column).  I know that I must edit the addClass and removeClass lines for first-child nth-child but I am not sure how to highlight the cell below the one that is currently highlighted.  Thanks in advance for any help!

```js
$("td").hover(function(){

  $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().first().addClass('highlight');

  $('tr:first-child th:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')').addClass('highlight');


},function(){

  $(this).removeClass("highlight").siblings().first().removeClass('highlight');

  $('tr:first-child th:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')').removeClass('highlight');

});
```

```css
table,th, td {
  
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size: 90%;
        
}

th, td {
    
    padding:8px;
    
}

td {
    
    text-align: center;
    
}

table {
    
    margin:0 auto;
    
}

td:click {
    
    background-color: blue;
}

.highlight {
    
    background-color:#E0E0E0;
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tr><th>Item #</th><th>1234567</th><th>7654321</th></tr><tr><th>Product</th><th><u>22oz Dark</u></th><th><u>12ct 4oz Dark</u></th></tr><tr><th>2016-01-01</th><td>9785</td><td>2478</td></tr><tr><th>2016-01-02</th><td>8754</td><td>2136</td></tr><tr><th>2016-01-03</th><td>13587</td><td>2203</td></tr><tr><th>2016-01-04</th><td>14111</td><td>3297</td></tr><tr><th>2016-01-05</th><td>13212</td><td>3101</td></tr><tr><th>2016-01-06</th><td>16335</td><td>3299</td></tr><tr><th>2016-01-07</th><td>15421</td><td>3100</td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to highlight the Product Name (second th down in column)

I think the snippet below is what you looking for, you could do this using **[`:eq() selector`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)** :

```
//Add the highlight using 
$('tr:eq(1) th:eq('+$(this).index()+')').addClass('highlight');

//Then remove the highlight using 
$('tr:eq(1) th:eq('+$(this).index()+')').removeClass('highlight');
```

`tr:eq(1)` will get the second row since `:eq()` is a 0 based, `th:eq('+$(this).index()+')` will select the first or second `th` based on the hovered `td` index.

Hope this helps.

```js
$("td").hover(function(){

  $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().first().addClass('highlight');

  $('tr:first-child th:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')').addClass('highlight');

$('tr:eq(1) th:eq('+$(this).index()+')').addClass('highlight');
  
},function(){

  $(this).removeClass("highlight").siblings().first().removeClass('highlight');

  $('tr:first-child th:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')').removeClass('highlight');

  $('tr:eq(1) th:eq('+$(this).index()+')').removeClass('highlight');
});
```

```css
table,th, td {
  
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size: 90%;
        
}

th, td {
    
    padding:8px;
    
}

td {
    
    text-align: center;
    
}

table {
    
    margin:0 auto;
    
}

td:click {
    
    background-color: blue;
}

.highlight {
    
    background-color:#E0E0E0;
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tr><th>Item #</th><th>1234567</th><th>7654321</th></tr><tr><th>Product</th><th><u>22oz Dark</u></th><th><u>12ct 4oz Dark</u></th></tr><tr><th>2016-01-01</th><td>9785</td><td>2478</td></tr><tr><th>2016-01-02</th><td>8754</td><td>2136</td></tr><tr><th>2016-01-03</th><td>13587</td><td>2203</td></tr><tr><th>2016-01-04</th><td>14111</td><td>3297</td></tr><tr><th>2016-01-05</th><td>13212</td><td>3101</td></tr><tr><th>2016-01-06</th><td>16335</td><td>3299</td></tr><tr><th>2016-01-07</th><td>15421</td><td>3100</td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to update the jQuery selector slightly, to target the second row of the table rather than the first:

```
$("td").hover(function(){

    $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().first().addClass('highlight');

    $('tr:nth-child(2) th:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')').addClass('highlight');


},function(){

    $(this).removeClass("highlight").siblings().first().removeClass('highlight');

    $('tr:nth-child(2) th:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')').removeClass('highlight');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I updated your jQuery code and made it a bit cleaner and fixed your problem.

For that, I used internal jQuery functions like `.eq()` (works similar to the CSS `:nth-child`) to solve it.

```
$("td").hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().first().addClass('highlight');
    $('tr').eq(1).children('th').eq($(this).index()).addClass('highlight');


},function(){
    $(this).removeClass("highlight").siblings().first().removeClass('highlight');
    $('tr').eq(1).children('th').eq($(this).index()).removeClass('highlight');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

See below code. You just have to use `prev()` so it will highlight prevous `td`

```js
$("td").hover(function(){
                                
                $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().first().addClass('highlight');
                
                $('tr:nth-child(n+2) th:eq('+$(this).index()+')').addClass('highlight');
                        
                
            },function(){
                 $(this).removeClass('highlight').siblings().first().removeClass('highlight');
               
                
                $('tr:nth-child(n+2) th:eq('+$(this).index()+')').removeClass('highlight');
                
            });
```

```css
table,th, td {
  
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size: 90%;
        
}

th, td {
    
    padding:8px;
    
}

td {
    
    text-align: center;
    
}

table {
    
    margin:0 auto;
    
}

td:click {
    
    background-color: blue;
}

.highlight {
    
    background-color:#E0E0E0;
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tr><th>Item #</th><th>1234567</th><th>7654321</th></tr><tr><th>Product</th><th><u>22oz Dark</u></th><th><u>12ct 4oz Dark</u></th></tr><tr><th>2016-01-01</th><td>9785</td><td>2478</td></tr><tr><th>2016-01-02</th><td>8754</td><td>2136</td></tr><tr><th>2016-01-03</th><td>13587</td><td>2203</td></tr><tr><th>2016-01-04</th><td>14111</td><td>3297</td></tr><tr><th>2016-01-05</th><td>13212</td><td>3101</td></tr><tr><th>2016-01-06</th><td>16335</td><td>3299</td></tr><tr><th>2016-01-07</th><td>15421</td><td>3100</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: This is not correct, I do know that the changes need to be made to the first-child/nth-child lines.  You made changes to the line that highlights the product date instead.  Run the code above that you posted and you will see what I mean.  The mouse over cell, a date, and a product name is what should be highlighted.

Comment: @Brandon yes right,Now i have changed and its working according to your requirement

Comment: @BharatPatidar you code is actually still wrong.  By just clicking the Run Code Snippet you would easily see it isnt working properly.  Others above have already helped me get my issue fixed though.  Thanks for your help Zakaria Acharki !